# Hardware/Network equivalent to Automated Testing?

Tags: monitoring, automated-testing

I'd like to build out my network infrastructure by using a TDD approach. Specifically, I'm not sure what monitoring we will require, but if something fails, I'd like to be able to fix is then put in place a monitor of some sort to notify me of the failure the next time it occurs, hopefully before our users notice.

Our systems are/will be a mix of windows and Ubuntu boxes with a wide variety of switches and multiple locations across the country (yeah, legacy sucks).

I'm looking for something that's inexpensive (free is best) and that doesn't start out being way too complex.  I'd like it to grow with our monitoring requirements. Never being more than we need at any given time.

Am I out to lunch, or can someone offer suggestions?

Comment: Use "heartbeat" in your searches? And maybe tag this that way, too...

Comment: @dmckeee, I'm not following

Comment: A heartbeat is a generic term for an ongoing single passed from a remote application/computer to a central monitor. They are useful for keeping tabs on stuff which should continue running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you give [Spiceworks](http://spiceworks.com) a try. Spiceworks will go around the network a every set amount of time (5,10,15 minutes) and check if each computer is up and if something is down it will throw a warning which you can setup to send you an email.

Spiceworks is a also free and will always be free.